# Box Select Error: Active Object is Not a Selected Mesh

Tags: selection-tools

I'm trying to use the box select to select multiple objects in Object Mode, then Click "CTRL-J" to join the objects. Sometimes doing this results in the error message: "Active Object is not a selected mesh". It seems to be intermittent. I verified that the selected objects are meshes. It works by selecting objects individually and doing the "CTRL-J", but not always using the box select tool.

[image]

What could the problem be?
Using Blender 2.75a

EDIT: After looking at this more, I think the problem is that the error message is reversed. I think it should say: "Selected Object is not an active mesh", instead of "Active Object is not a selected mesh".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the message is right. And happens also selecting by hand, I just did it (blender 2.74 on this pc)

In blender, the "active object" is the last one selected.

But. suppose you have 3 objects and

1. You start selecting obj1: that is the active object, and is also selected
2. then you shift select obj2 and obj 3: now obj1,2,3 are all selected but obj3 is the active (last selected)
3. then you (eg: by mistake), click again on obj1: now obj2,3 are selected, obj1 is not BUT it is the last you selected (and then deselected) so, to blender obj1 is still the "active" object, but is not selected

exactly what the message says...

In your image, I see that in the outliner this is visible. the active object (not selected) is backpole.003 (its text is highlighted but the triangle icon has no circle background) while backpole.009 and backpole.019 are selected (the triangle icon has a circle purple background)

If you ask me, it could be a bug in the selection behaviour, but... this explains the message you get. It could be that box selection replicates this behaviour or something similar with the same effect

Comment: OK, thanks. It appears you are right. What I do now is make sure nothing is already selected/active before doing the box select. Now it seems the error message no longer displays. It seems the error message occurs when something is already selected, and then you do a box select which contains a mesh which has already been selected.